# How to use wait handles in C# threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have three threads in my program and I want that when thread one finishes it signals thread 2 to start and when thread 2 finishes it should signal thread 3 to start.

How can I achieve this, I know there are wait handles to do that in C#, but I don't know how to use them ?

Following is the code of my program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(Task1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(Task2);
            Thread t3 = new Thread(Task3);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void Task1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 1:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task1" );
            }
        }
        public static void Task2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 2:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task2");
            }
        }
        public static void Task3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 3:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task3");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass `t2` as argument in `t1.Start` then in the end of `Task1` call `t2.Start()` using the argument you got. For this to work, use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass events into the threaded functions that indicate what to signal when each one has finished and what to wait on before they run. Take a look at the (untested) code below to see what I mean:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(Task1);
            ManualResetEvent e1=new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Thread t2 = new Thread(Task2);
            ManualResetEvent e2=new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Thread t3 = new Thread(Task3);
            ManualResetEvent e3=new ManualResetEvent(false);

            t1.Start(()=>Task1(e1));
            t2.Start(()=>Task2(e1,e2));
            t3.Start(()=>Task3(e2,e3);

            Console.Read();

            t1.Join();
            t2.Join();
            t3.Join();
        }

        public static void Task1(EventWaitHandle handle)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 1:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task1" );
            }
            handle.Set();

        }
        public static void Task2(EventWaitHandle waitFor, EventWaitHandle handle)
        {
            waitFor.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 2:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task2");
            }

            handle.Set();
        }
        public static void Task3(EventWaitHandle waitFor, EventWaitHandle handle)
        {
            waitFor.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("I am assigned task 3:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task3");
            }

            handle.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your wait handle names are off currently.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: That's right. That way Task2 and Task3 wont will block initially. Task1 will set the handle that Task2 is waiting on. Then, when Task2 has finished it will set the handle that Task3 is waiting on.

Comment: I'm not following you. They're declared in main() and each TaskXXX method has the handles passed in. Where do you think there's a declaration missing?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that  you want to run Tasks 1 - 3 to execute *synchronously*. So, you might as well do:

```
Task1();
Task2();
Task3();
```

If you want to offload the execution of these tasks to another thread, you can do:

```
static void RunTasks()
{
    Task1();
    Task2();
    Task3();
}

static void Main()
{
   new Thread(RunTasks).Start();
}
```

If you really wanted each task to run on a separate *thread*, and wait for the previous task to finish, you can use the [**`Thread.Join`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) method.

**EDIT**:

Since you really want to use wait-handles to accomplish this, take a look at the [**`ManualResetEvent`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) class.

> Notifies one or more waiting threads
>   that an event has occurred.

Call the `WaitOne` method on it to wait on the event, and the `Set` method to signal it.

Example (horribly contrived code):

```
var afterT1Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var afterT2Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Thread t1 = new Thread(() => { Task1(); afterT1Event.Set(); });
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => { afterT1Event.WaitOne(); Task2(); afterT2Event.Set(); });
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => { afterT2Event.WaitOne(); Task3(); });

t1.Start();
t2.Start();
t3.Start();
```

Comment: My purpose of the question was to learn how wait handles work ? So, please give me example of that ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use WaitHandles to acheive these then you could do the following:

declare the following two fields:

```
static ManualResetEvent handle1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static ManualResetEvent handle2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

then at the end of Task1, add this:

```
    handle1.Set();
```

at the beginning of Task2, add:

```
    handle1.WaitOne();
```

then at the end, add

```
    handle2.Set();
```

then finally at the beginning of Task3 add

```
    handle2.WaitOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels very artificial, almost like homework...

... but basically you can use `Join` on a thread to wait for it.

Or the old msdn tutorial/example is very reasonable on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use ManualResetEvents and WaitHandle.WaitAny.  Basically when one thread is done you would notify the other thread by using a ManualResetEvent (ManualResetEvent.Set()).

```
ManualResetEvent threadFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

//You would set this in the thread that has finished
threadFinished.Set()

//You would use this in the thread that you want to wait for this event to be signalled
int nWait = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new ManualResetEvent[] { threadFinished }, 10, true);

//if yes stop thread
if (nWait == 0)
{
    //Thread is finished
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think using [thread.join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) will be more simpler any other solution